# How to use GHDL to simulate generated XilinX IP?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

I have used the XilinX core generator in Vivado 2016.4 to generate the VHDL code for a divider like so:

[image: Select manage IP from starting window]

[image: Click New IP Location]

[image: Click Next]

[image: Select the part, Target Language, simulator and simulator Language and IP Location]

![Wait for Vivado to create the project](Wait for Vivado to create the project.jpg)

[image: Select Math functions folder and then Dividers and then Divider Generator]

[image: Select Variable Widths]

[image: Click generate to generate files]

[image: Wait for Vivado to generate files]

[image: It has now generated the files.]

I have then used the added the template info in div_gen_0.vho like so:

```
library ieee;      
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity DividingExample is
  port (
    clk : in std_logic;
    reset : in std_logic;
    InputSignal : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    OutputSignal : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
    );
end DividingExample;

architecture behaviour of DividingExample is
-- declarations

  COMPONENT div_gen_0                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    PORT (                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      aclk : IN STD_LOGIC;                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      s_axis_divisor_tvalid : IN STD_LOGIC;                                                                                                                                                                                              
      s_axis_divisor_tdata : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);                                                                                                                                                                           
      s_axis_dividend_tvalid : IN STD_LOGIC;                                                                                                                                                                                             
      s_axis_dividend_tdata : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);                                                                                                                                                                          
      m_axis_dout_tvalid : OUT STD_LOGIC;                                                                                                                                                                                                
      m_axis_dout_tdata : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 DOWNTO 0)                                                                                                                                                                              
    );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  END COMPONENT;

  signal numerator : integer;
begin
-- behaviour

  DIVIDER : div_gen_0                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    PORT MAP (                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      aclk => aclk,                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      s_axis_divisor_tvalid => s_axis_divisor_tvalid,                                                                                                                                                                                    
      s_axis_divisor_tdata => s_axis_divisor_tdata,                                                                                                                                                                                      
      s_axis_dividend_tvalid => s_axis_dividend_tvalid,                                                                                                                                                                                  
      s_axis_dividend_tdata => s_axis_dividend_tdata,                                                                                                                                                                                    
      m_axis_dout_tvalid => m_axis_dout_tvalid,                                                                                                                                                                                          
      m_axis_dout_tdata => m_axis_dout_tdata                                                                                                                                                                                             
    ); 

  process(clk)
  begin
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
      if(reset = '1') then
        -- reset values
        numerator <= 1000;  
      else
        -- calculate value to be output
        -- OutputSignal <= numerator/to_integer(signed(InputSignal))
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
end behaviour;
```

This part compiles fine with GHDL, however the generated synth/div_gen_0.vhd file does not. When compiles with GHDL like so:

ghdl -a synth/div_gen_0.vhd

I get the following output:

```
synth/div_gen_0.vhd:56:9: cannot find resource library "div_gen_v5_1_11"
synth/div_gen_0.vhd:57:21: unit "div_gen_v5_1_11" not found in 'library "div_gen_v5_1_11"'
```

And I cannot use the divider as the Divider unit is unbound. Is this an issue I can get around by specifying a different Target Simulator in Vivado or must I use a package like ModelSim in order to use this library?

div_gen_0.vhd contains the following code:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

LIBRARY div_gen_v5_1_11;
USE div_gen_v5_1_11.div_gen_v5_1_11;

ENTITY div_gen_0 IS
  PORT (
    aclk : IN STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_divisor_tvalid : IN STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_divisor_tdata : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    s_axis_dividend_tvalid : IN STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_dividend_tdata : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    m_axis_dout_tvalid : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    m_axis_dout_tdata : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 DOWNTO 0)
  );
END div_gen_0;

ARCHITECTURE div_gen_0_arch OF div_gen_0 IS
  ATTRIBUTE DowngradeIPIdentifiedWarnings : STRING;
  ATTRIBUTE DowngradeIPIdentifiedWarnings OF div_gen_0_arch: ARCHITECTURE IS "yes";
  COMPONENT div_gen_v5_1_11 IS
    GENERIC (
      C_XDEVICEFAMILY : STRING;
      C_HAS_ARESETN : INTEGER;
      C_HAS_ACLKEN : INTEGER;
      C_LATENCY : INTEGER;
      ALGORITHM_TYPE : INTEGER;
      DIVISOR_WIDTH : INTEGER;
      DIVIDEND_WIDTH : INTEGER;
      SIGNED_B : INTEGER;
      DIVCLK_SEL : INTEGER;
      FRACTIONAL_B : INTEGER;
      FRACTIONAL_WIDTH : INTEGER;
      C_HAS_DIV_BY_ZERO : INTEGER;
      C_THROTTLE_SCHEME : INTEGER;
      C_TLAST_RESOLUTION : INTEGER;
      C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER : INTEGER;
      C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TLAST : INTEGER;
      C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TDATA_WIDTH : INTEGER;
      C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER_WIDTH : INTEGER;
      C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER : INTEGER;
      C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TLAST : INTEGER;
      C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TDATA_WIDTH : INTEGER;
      C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER_WIDTH : INTEGER;
      C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TDATA_WIDTH : INTEGER;
      C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TUSER_WIDTH : INTEGER
    );
    PORT (
      aclk : IN STD_LOGIC;
      aclken : IN STD_LOGIC;
      aresetn : IN STD_LOGIC;
      s_axis_divisor_tvalid : IN STD_LOGIC;
      s_axis_divisor_tready : OUT STD_LOGIC;
      s_axis_divisor_tuser : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 DOWNTO 0);
      s_axis_divisor_tlast : IN STD_LOGIC;
      s_axis_divisor_tdata : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
      s_axis_dividend_tvalid : IN STD_LOGIC;
      s_axis_dividend_tready : OUT STD_LOGIC;
      s_axis_dividend_tuser : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 DOWNTO 0);
      s_axis_dividend_tlast : IN STD_LOGIC;
      s_axis_dividend_tdata : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
      m_axis_dout_tvalid : OUT STD_LOGIC;
      m_axis_dout_tready : IN STD_LOGIC;
      m_axis_dout_tuser : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 DOWNTO 0);
      m_axis_dout_tlast : OUT STD_LOGIC;
      m_axis_dout_tdata : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 DOWNTO 0)
    );
  END COMPONENT div_gen_v5_1_11;
  ATTRIBUTE X_CORE_INFO : STRING;
  ATTRIBUTE X_CORE_INFO OF div_gen_0_arch: ARCHITECTURE IS "div_gen_v5_1_11,Vivado 2016.4";
  ATTRIBUTE CHECK_LICENSE_TYPE : STRING;
  ATTRIBUTE CHECK_LICENSE_TYPE OF div_gen_0_arch : ARCHITECTURE IS "div_gen_0,div_gen_v5_1_11,{}";
  ATTRIBUTE CORE_GENERATION_INFO : STRING;
  ATTRIBUTE CORE_GENERATION_INFO OF div_gen_0_arch: ARCHITECTURE IS "div_gen_0,div_gen_v5_1_11,{x_ipProduct=Vivado 2016.4,x_ipVendor=xilinx.com,x_ipLibrary=ip,x_ipName=div_gen,x_ipVersion=5.1,x_ipCoreRevision=11,x_ipLanguage=VHDL,x_ipSimLanguage=VHDL,C_XDEVICEFAMILY=kintex7,C_HAS_ARESETN=0,C_HAS_ACLKEN=0,C_LATENCY=36,ALGORITHM_TYPE=1,DIVISOR_WIDTH=32,DIVIDEND_WIDTH=32,SIGNED_B=1,DIVCLK_SEL=1,FRACTIONAL_B=0,FRACTIONAL_WIDTH=32,C_HAS_DIV_BY_ZERO=0,C_THROTTLE_SCHEME=3,C_TLAST_RESOLUTION=0,C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER=0,C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TLAST=0,C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TDA" & 
"TA_WIDTH=32,C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER_WIDTH=1,C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER=0,C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TLAST=0,C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TDATA_WIDTH=32,C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER_WIDTH=1,C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TDATA_WIDTH=64,C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TUSER_WIDTH=1}";
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO : STRING;
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF aclk: SIGNAL IS "xilinx.com:signal:clock:1.0 aclk_intf CLK";
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF s_axis_divisor_tvalid: SIGNAL IS "xilinx.com:interface:axis:1.0 S_AXIS_DIVISOR TVALID";
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF s_axis_divisor_tdata: SIGNAL IS "xilinx.com:interface:axis:1.0 S_AXIS_DIVISOR TDATA";
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF s_axis_dividend_tvalid: SIGNAL IS "xilinx.com:interface:axis:1.0 S_AXIS_DIVIDEND TVALID";
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF s_axis_dividend_tdata: SIGNAL IS "xilinx.com:interface:axis:1.0 S_AXIS_DIVIDEND TDATA";
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF m_axis_dout_tvalid: SIGNAL IS "xilinx.com:interface:axis:1.0 M_AXIS_DOUT TVALID";
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF m_axis_dout_tdata: SIGNAL IS "xilinx.com:interface:axis:1.0 M_AXIS_DOUT TDATA";
BEGIN
  U0 : div_gen_v5_1_11
    GENERIC MAP (
      C_XDEVICEFAMILY => "kintex7",
      C_HAS_ARESETN => 0,
      C_HAS_ACLKEN => 0,
      C_LATENCY => 36,
      ALGORITHM_TYPE => 1,
      DIVISOR_WIDTH => 32,
      DIVIDEND_WIDTH => 32,
      SIGNED_B => 1,
      DIVCLK_SEL => 1,
      FRACTIONAL_B => 0,
      FRACTIONAL_WIDTH => 32,
      C_HAS_DIV_BY_ZERO => 0,
      C_THROTTLE_SCHEME => 3,
      C_TLAST_RESOLUTION => 0,
      C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER => 0,
      C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TLAST => 0,
      C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TDATA_WIDTH => 32,
      C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER_WIDTH => 1,
      C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER => 0,
      C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TLAST => 0,
      C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TDATA_WIDTH => 32,
      C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER_WIDTH => 1,
      C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TDATA_WIDTH => 64,
      C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TUSER_WIDTH => 1
    )
    PORT MAP (
      aclk => aclk,
      aclken => '1',
      aresetn => '1',
      s_axis_divisor_tvalid => s_axis_divisor_tvalid,
      s_axis_divisor_tuser => STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(0, 1)),
          s_axis_divisor_tlast => '0',
          s_axis_divisor_tdata => s_axis_divisor_tdata,
          s_axis_dividend_tvalid => s_axis_dividend_tvalid,
          s_axis_dividend_tuser => STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(0, 1)),
          s_axis_dividend_tlast => '0',
          s_axis_dividend_tdata => s_axis_dividend_tdata,
          m_axis_dout_tvalid => m_axis_dout_tvalid,
          m_axis_dout_tready => '0',
          m_axis_dout_tdata => m_axis_dout_tdata
          );
END div_gen_0_arch;
```

It is the line LIBRARY div_gen_v5_1_11; that is the problem as Brian points out below. I therefore need the VHDL code to compile to this library the tree structure of the directory created by vivado looks like so:

```
.
├── cmodel
│   ├── div_gen_v5_1_bitacc_cmodel_lin64.zip
│   └── div_gen_v5_1_bitacc_cmodel_nt64.zip
├── demo_tb
│   └── tb_div_gen_0.vhd
├── div_gen_0.dcp
├── div_gen_0_ooc.xdc
├── div_gen_0_sim_netlist.v
├── div_gen_0_sim_netlist.vhdl
├── div_gen_0_stub.v
├── div_gen_0_stub.vhdl
├── div_gen_0.veo
├── div_gen_0.vho
├── div_gen_0.xci
├── div_gen_0.xml
├── doc
│   └── div_gen_v5_1_changelog.txt
├── hdl
│   ├── axi_utils_v2_0_vh_rfs.vhd
│   ├── div_gen_v5_1_vh_rfs.vhd
│   ├── floating_point_v7_0_vh_rfs.vhd
│   ├── mult_gen_v12_0_vh_rfs.vhd
│   ├── xbip_bram18k_v3_0_vh_rfs.vhd
│   ├── xbip_dsp48_addsub_v3_0_vh_rfs.vhd
│   ├── xbip_dsp48_multadd_v3_0_vh_rfs.vhd
│   ├── xbip_dsp48_mult_v3_0_vh_rfs.vhd
│   ├── xbip_dsp48_wrapper_v3_0_vh_rfs.vhd
│   ├── xbip_pipe_v3_0_vh_rfs.vhd
│   └── xbip_utils_v3_0_vh_rfs.vhd
├── sim
│   └── div_gen_0.vhd
└── synth
    └── div_gen_0.vhd
```

I have discovered, with the help of Brian that the `div_gen_0_sim_netlist.vhdl` file compiles into the library. This file contains the following:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VCOMPONENTS.ALL;
entity div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 is 
  port (
    aclk : in STD_LOGIC;
    aclken : in STD_LOGIC;
    aresetn : in STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_divisor_tvalid : in STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_divisor_tready : out STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_divisor_tuser : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 0 to 0 );
    s_axis_divisor_tlast : in STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_divisor_tdata : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
    s_axis_dividend_tvalid : in STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_dividend_tready : out STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_dividend_tuser : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 0 to 0 );
    s_axis_dividend_tlast : in STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_dividend_tdata : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
    m_axis_dout_tvalid : out STD_LOGIC;
    m_axis_dout_tready : in STD_LOGIC;
    m_axis_dout_tuser : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 0 to 0 );
    m_axis_dout_tlast : out STD_LOGIC;
    m_axis_dout_tdata : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 63 downto 0 )
  );
  attribute ALGORITHM_TYPE : integer;
  attribute ALGORITHM_TYPE of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 1;
  attribute C_HAS_ACLKEN : integer;
  attribute C_HAS_ACLKEN of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_ARESETN : integer;
  attribute C_HAS_ARESETN of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_DIV_BY_ZERO : integer;
  attribute C_HAS_DIV_BY_ZERO of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TLAST : integer;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TLAST of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER : integer;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TLAST : integer;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TLAST of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER : integer;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 0;
  attribute C_LATENCY : integer;
  attribute C_LATENCY of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 36;
  attribute C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TDATA_WIDTH : integer;
  attribute C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TDATA_WIDTH of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 64;
  attribute C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TUSER_WIDTH : integer;
  attribute C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TUSER_WIDTH of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 1;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TDATA_WIDTH : integer;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TDATA_WIDTH of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 32;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER_WIDTH : integer;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER_WIDTH of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 1;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TDATA_WIDTH : integer;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TDATA_WIDTH of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 32;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER_WIDTH : integer;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER_WIDTH of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 1;
  attribute C_THROTTLE_SCHEME : integer;
  attribute C_THROTTLE_SCHEME of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 3;
  attribute C_TLAST_RESOLUTION : integer;
  attribute C_TLAST_RESOLUTION of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 0;
  attribute C_XDEVICEFAMILY : string;
  attribute C_XDEVICEFAMILY of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is "kintex7";
  attribute DIVCLK_SEL : integer;
  attribute DIVCLK_SEL of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 1;
  attribute DIVIDEND_WIDTH : integer;
  attribute DIVIDEND_WIDTH of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 32;
  attribute DIVISOR_WIDTH : integer;
  attribute DIVISOR_WIDTH of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 32;
  attribute FRACTIONAL_B : integer;
  attribute FRACTIONAL_B of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 0;
  attribute FRACTIONAL_WIDTH : integer;
  attribute FRACTIONAL_WIDTH of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 32;
  attribute ORIG_REF_NAME : string;
  attribute ORIG_REF_NAME of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is "div_gen_v5_1_11";
  attribute SIGNED_B : integer;
  attribute SIGNED_B of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is 1;
  attribute downgradeipidentifiedwarnings : string;
  attribute downgradeipidentifiedwarnings of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 : entity is "yes";
end div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11;

architecture STRUCTURE of div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 is
  signal \<const0>\ : STD_LOGIC;
  signal \<const1>\ : STD_LOGIC;
  signal NLW_i_synth_m_axis_dout_tlast_UNCONNECTED : STD_LOGIC;
  signal NLW_i_synth_s_axis_dividend_tready_UNCONNECTED : STD_LOGIC;
  signal NLW_i_synth_s_axis_divisor_tready_UNCONNECTED : STD_LOGIC;
  signal NLW_i_synth_m_axis_dout_tuser_UNCONNECTED : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 0 to 0 );
  attribute C_HAS_ACLKEN of i_synth : label is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_ARESETN of i_synth : label is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TLAST of i_synth : label is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER of i_synth : label is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TLAST of i_synth : label is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER of i_synth : label is 0;
  attribute C_LATENCY of i_synth : label is 36;
  attribute C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TDATA_WIDTH of i_synth : label is 64;
  attribute C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TUSER_WIDTH of i_synth : label is 1;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TDATA_WIDTH of i_synth : label is 32;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER_WIDTH of i_synth : label is 1;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TDATA_WIDTH of i_synth : label is 32;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER_WIDTH of i_synth : label is 1;
  attribute C_THROTTLE_SCHEME of i_synth : label is 3;
  attribute C_TLAST_RESOLUTION of i_synth : label is 0;
  attribute algorithm_type of i_synth : label is 1;
  attribute c_has_div_by_zero of i_synth : label is 0;
  attribute c_xdevicefamily of i_synth : label is "kintex7";
  attribute divclk_sel of i_synth : label is 1;
  attribute dividend_width of i_synth : label is 32;
  attribute divisor_width of i_synth : label is 32;
  attribute downgradeipidentifiedwarnings of i_synth : label is "yes";
  attribute fractional_b of i_synth : label is 0;
  attribute fractional_width of i_synth : label is 32;
  attribute signed_b of i_synth : label is 1;
begin
  m_axis_dout_tlast <= \<const0>\;
  m_axis_dout_tuser(0) <= \<const0>\;
  s_axis_dividend_tready <= \<const1>\;
  s_axis_divisor_tready <= \<const1>\;
GND: unisim.vcomponents.GND
     port map (
      G => \<const0>\
    );
VCC: unisim.vcomponents.VCC
     port map (
      P => \<const1>\
    );
i_synth: entity work.div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11
  port map (
    aclk => aclk,
    aclken => '0',
    aresetn => '0',
    m_axis_dout_tdata(63 downto 0) => m_axis_dout_tdata(63 downto 0),
    m_axis_dout_tlast => NLW_i_synth_m_axis_dout_tlast_UNCONNECTED,
    m_axis_dout_tready => '0',
    m_axis_dout_tuser(0) => NLW_i_synth_m_axis_dout_tuser_UNCONNECTED(0),
    m_axis_dout_tvalid => m_axis_dout_tvalid,
    s_axis_dividend_tdata(31 downto 0) => s_axis_dividend_tdata(31 downto 0),
    s_axis_dividend_tlast => '0',
    s_axis_dividend_tready => NLW_i_synth_s_axis_dividend_tready_UNCONNECTED,
    s_axis_dividend_tuser(0) => '0',
    s_axis_dividend_tvalid => s_axis_dividend_tvalid,
    s_axis_divisor_tdata(31 downto 0) => s_axis_divisor_tdata(31 downto 0),
    s_axis_divisor_tlast => '0',
    s_axis_divisor_tready => NLW_i_synth_s_axis_divisor_tready_UNCONNECTED,
    s_axis_divisor_tuser(0) => '0',
    s_axis_divisor_tvalid => s_axis_divisor_tvalid
    );
end STRUCTURE;
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VCOMPONENTS.ALL;
entity div_gen_0 is
  port (
    aclk : in STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_divisor_tvalid : in STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_divisor_tdata : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
    s_axis_dividend_tvalid : in STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_dividend_tdata : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
    m_axis_dout_tvalid : out STD_LOGIC;
    m_axis_dout_tdata : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 63 downto 0 )
  );
  attribute NotValidForBitStream : boolean;
  attribute NotValidForBitStream of div_gen_0 : entity is true;
  attribute CHECK_LICENSE_TYPE : string;
  attribute CHECK_LICENSE_TYPE of div_gen_0 : entity is "div_gen_0,div_gen_v5_1_11,{}";
  attribute downgradeipidentifiedwarnings : string;
  attribute downgradeipidentifiedwarnings of div_gen_0 : entity is "yes";
  attribute x_core_info : string;
  attribute x_core_info of div_gen_0 : entity is "div_gen_v5_1_11,Vivado 2016.4";
end div_gen_0;

architecture STRUCTURE of div_gen_0 is
  signal NLW_U0_m_axis_dout_tlast_UNCONNECTED : STD_LOGIC;
  signal NLW_U0_s_axis_dividend_tready_UNCONNECTED : STD_LOGIC;
  signal NLW_U0_s_axis_divisor_tready_UNCONNECTED : STD_LOGIC;
  signal NLW_U0_m_axis_dout_tuser_UNCONNECTED : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 0 to 0 );
  attribute C_HAS_ACLKEN : integer;
  attribute C_HAS_ACLKEN of U0 : label is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_ARESETN : integer;
  attribute C_HAS_ARESETN of U0 : label is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TLAST : integer;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TLAST of U0 : label is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER : integer;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER of U0 : label is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TLAST : integer;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TLAST of U0 : label is 0;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER : integer;
  attribute C_HAS_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER of U0 : label is 0;
  attribute C_LATENCY : integer;
  attribute C_LATENCY of U0 : label is 36;
  attribute C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TDATA_WIDTH : integer;
  attribute C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TDATA_WIDTH of U0 : label is 64;
  attribute C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TUSER_WIDTH : integer;
  attribute C_M_AXIS_DOUT_TUSER_WIDTH of U0 : label is 1;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TDATA_WIDTH : integer;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TDATA_WIDTH of U0 : label is 32;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER_WIDTH : integer;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVIDEND_TUSER_WIDTH of U0 : label is 1;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TDATA_WIDTH : integer;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TDATA_WIDTH of U0 : label is 32;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER_WIDTH : integer;
  attribute C_S_AXIS_DIVISOR_TUSER_WIDTH of U0 : label is 1;
  attribute C_THROTTLE_SCHEME : integer;
  attribute C_THROTTLE_SCHEME of U0 : label is 3;
  attribute C_TLAST_RESOLUTION : integer;
  attribute C_TLAST_RESOLUTION of U0 : label is 0;
  attribute algorithm_type : integer;
  attribute algorithm_type of U0 : label is 1;
  attribute c_has_div_by_zero : integer;
  attribute c_has_div_by_zero of U0 : label is 0;
  attribute c_xdevicefamily : string;
  attribute c_xdevicefamily of U0 : label is "kintex7";
  attribute divclk_sel : integer;
  attribute divclk_sel of U0 : label is 1;
  attribute dividend_width : integer;
  attribute dividend_width of U0 : label is 32;
  attribute divisor_width : integer;
  attribute divisor_width of U0 : label is 32;
  attribute downgradeipidentifiedwarnings of U0 : label is "yes";
  attribute fractional_b : integer;
  attribute fractional_b of U0 : label is 0;
  attribute fractional_width : integer;
  attribute fractional_width of U0 : label is 32;
  attribute signed_b : integer;
  attribute signed_b of U0 : label is 1;
begin
U0: entity work.div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11
     port map (
      aclk => aclk,
      aclken => '1',
      aresetn => '1',
      m_axis_dout_tdata(63 downto 0) => m_axis_dout_tdata(63 downto 0),
      m_axis_dout_tlast => NLW_U0_m_axis_dout_tlast_UNCONNECTED,
      m_axis_dout_tready => '0',
      m_axis_dout_tuser(0) => NLW_U0_m_axis_dout_tuser_UNCONNECTED(0),
      m_axis_dout_tvalid => m_axis_dout_tvalid,
      s_axis_dividend_tdata(31 downto 0) => s_axis_dividend_tdata(31 downto 0),
          s_axis_dividend_tlast => '0',
          s_axis_dividend_tready => NLW_U0_s_axis_dividend_tready_UNCONNECTED,
          s_axis_dividend_tuser(0) => '0',
          s_axis_dividend_tvalid => s_axis_dividend_tvalid,
          s_axis_divisor_tdata(31 downto 0) => s_axis_divisor_tdata(31 downto 0),
          s_axis_divisor_tlast => '0',
          s_axis_divisor_tready => NLW_U0_s_axis_divisor_tready_UNCONNECTED,
          s_axis_divisor_tuser(0) => '0',
          s_axis_divisor_tvalid => s_axis_divisor_tvalid
          );
end STRUCTURE;
```

Comment: You need Vivado to generate `div_gen_0` in VHDL. Then compile that in ghdl. Apparently you HAVE a `div_gen_0.vhd` file (which you haven't shown us) but it refers to something else - that too needs to be in VHDL - and compiled into the named library, e.g. `ghdl -a --work=div_gen_v5_1_11 div_gen_v5_1_11.vhd`. But if that file is only available in Verilog for some stupid reason, then you can't use ghdl, it's a VHDL-only simulator.

Comment: I have added some more information into my question containing the contents of the div_gen_0.vhd file. Do you have any idea which file should be compiled to the named library?

Comment: The obvious place to start is the `hdl` folder, specifically the `div_gen_v5_1_vh_rfs.vhd` file. My guess is it'll use the other contents of that folder to build `div_gen_v5_1_11`. If you want to test that component on its own, Xilinx provide a `demo_tb` as a starting point.

Comment: It appears to be encrypted. I've added the code to my post.

Comment: At this point I can only point you to Xilinx tech support. My approach would be to eliminate proprietary IP from the design, (looking at the IEEE 2008 synthesisable fixed/floating point libs for example), while pointing out prominently to my Xilinx sales engineer that, as a consequence, I am no longer tied to a specific FPGA vendor.

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help, it's a shame that there isn't as big of an open-source scene in FPGA development as software development. I'll take a look at those libraries.

Comment: There IS a `div_gen_0_sim_netlist.vhdl` in there. Is it compilable? (using either Unisims or Simprims, which can be compiled in ghdl) That might be provided by Xilinx as an alternative route for non-proprietary simulators. It's probably gate level, and thus slow...

Comment: It does appear to be, when I compile it it cannot find the "unisim" library, where could I obtain the unisim library? I haven't come across it before.

Comment: I see it appears to come from the XilinX software so I should be able to find the unisim VHDL file inside my Vivado installation and compile that with ghdl?

Comment: https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/blob/master/libraries/vendors/README.md

Comment: I have now solved the library issues, I can compile unisim and div_gen_v5_11_1 like so: `ghdl -a --work=unisim div_gen_0/unisims/unisim_VCOMP.vhd`                                                           
`ghdl -a --work=div_gen_v5_1_11 div_gen_0/div_gen_0_sim_netlist.vhdl`. However when I try to compile the div_gen_0.VHD file (which is generated by vivado) I get the following errors:

Comment: `sim/div_gen_0.vhd:123:33: no named entities "aclk" in declarative part`
`sim/div_gen_0.vhd:124:33: no named entities "s_axis_divisor_tvalid" in declarative part`
`sim/div_gen_0.vhd:125:33: no named entities "s_axis_divisor_tdata" in declarative part`
`sim/div_gen_0.vhd:126:33: no named entities "s_axis_dividend_tvalid" in declarative part`
`sim/div_gen_0.vhd:127:33: no named entities "s_axis_dividend_tdata" in declarative part`
`sim/div_gen_0.vhd:128:33: no named entities "m_axis_dout_tvalid" in declarative part`

Comment: The contents of the div_gen_0.VHD file is in my original post

Comment: I have commented out those lines as they appear to not affect the functionality of the code. However I am now getting another issue. I get the following warning `sim/div_gen_0.vhd:131:3:warning: ''u0'' is not bound`
`sim/div_gen_0.vhd:71:14:warning: (in 'default configuration of div_gen_0(div_gen_0_arch)')`
`sim/div_gen_0.vhd:131:3:warning: ''u0'' is not bound`
`sim/div_gen_0.vhd:71:14:warning: (in 'default configuration of div_gen_0(div_gen_0_arch)')`

Comment: I have also changed line 6 of the original div_gen_0.VHD file so that it reads `USE div_gen_v5_1_11.div_gen_v5_1_11;` this could be the issue.

Comment: I have also tried replacing line 6 with `USE div_gen_v5_1_11.div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11; ` and this results in exactly the same issue.

Comment: I have added the contents of div_gen_0_sim_netlist.vhdl to the original question.

Comment: Looks like a mismatch between the `div_gen_v5_1_11` component, and the (supposedly matching) entity in the `div_gen_0_sim_netlist.vhdl` file (or the Unisims file) - look at these... Also read the testbench they supplied, see how it works, try compiling/simulating it in ghdl..

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at those and see if I can work out where the mismatch is. While I have your attention the reason I am trying to do this in the first place is that I need to implement a division by an integer which is calculated on the fly (see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41241377/how-to-use-the-xilinx-division-ip-core) is there another way to handle this? All I need to evaulate is the simple expression `B/A` where both of these variables are integers calculated iteratively in the code.

Comment: Without details, no comment. But if A is limited in range, I'd use it to index a table of reciprocals, so I could multiply instead. Or I think you could roll your own integer division with less fuss than this.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for all your help, it has been invaluable.

Comment: If you look in your last file (`entity div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11 is`) you'll find `U0: entity work.div_gen_0_div_gen_v5_1_11`, where that entity and architecture pair is missing (one pair is in library div_gen_v5_1_11 used in  div_gen_0 one used in div_gen_v5_1_11.div_gen_v5_1_11 from library work). You have no actual VHDL model of the divider present in the code you've shown. It can't simulate with what you've shown. Your dividing_example is also incomplete (and wrong).